# Why does a god/godlike being care about mortal?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, gods

Jimmy the Magician has killed God, razed Mount Olympus, and cut down Yggdrasil. He can create and destroy planets at will, reverse time, and rewrite the laws of physics as he sees fit.

But for some reason, Jimmy doesn't raze the Earth or enslave the human race. Even stranger, Jimmy *helps* people sometimes, in very minor ways.

Why would he be so isolationist?

Humans don't entertain Jimmy, and anyone who could've held a gun to his head is six feet under.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *MxK*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: is little Jimmy fast asleep?

Comment: Hello MxK Welcome to world building. It would appear that Jimmy is actually a God himself if he can rewrite the laws of physics and reverse time. In fact it looks like you are asking why God would be isolationist. I think your question might be better addressed to the philosophy SE rather than world building.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you can do anything you don't want to do anything. Imagine Minecraft minus all the dangers. It would be boring.

Also the statement "he don't raze the Earth" is untrue. As you mentioned he can reverse time. We call that "quick save/load" function. The result is as in the comic below.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Same reason you don't go out into the forest to kick over termite hills, even though you can. You are looking at Jimmy with your human eyes and your human-centric brain, but from the perspective of Jimmy we are nothing. He can make planets, he can make species, he can do *anything*.

Why would he care about us at all? He probably sometimes helps us for his own, weird motivations, his entertainment, just to see what would happen, whatever. We put out birdfood in winter, just because we like the chirping of the birds. We sometimes rescue stray animals because we have some weird inborn desire to preserve living things. And sometimes we stomp on things that annoy us, just like that.

Jimmy doesn't enslave humanity for the same reason we don't enslave ants: they offer nothing of value. Jimmy doesn't destroy the earth for the same reason we don't go out of our way to destroy anthills: because they are not in the way, so why bother? Jimmy sometimes helps people for the same reason we sometimes help creatures we come across: for our own motivations. And Jimmy *will* exterminate the earth if it ever gets in his way, just like we *will* pour concrete over anthills when building a house without even checking to see if anything is living there.

We've just been lucky so far.

Answer (score 5):

Jimmy's playground.

Have you ever noticed a line of ants going from somewhere to their nest. Some times you put a block in the line to see what they do. Do they go around? Do they move the blockage?

Some times you just step on them and see the rest swarm and try to help or carry the body over to the nest.

And some times.... **some times** you build a little bridge and help them across a tiny chasm.

To me, that's Jimmy. He's the supreme being and he has nothing better to do than play around with his little ants all day.

Comment: Though the OP did say, "Humans don't entertain Jimmy"

Answer (score 1):

**Jimmy is in love with a human**

And therefore does not wish to make his darling unhappy by harming other humans, or maybe just has a soft spot for them in general because of his love for this one.

or...

**Jimmy *is* a human**

He ascended to Godhood or Supermage or whatever he is now, from his humble beginnings as a puny Earthling, and so out of a sense of (for want of a better word) patriotism, or respect for his "roots", he doesn't erase them from the universe and in fact helps them.

He may even hold a belief that *all* humans can "evolve" as he did and looks forward to the day when humanity holds a higher place in the Cosmos, and so helps humans towards this goal, but of course he thinks they should get there "naturally" through hard work (as he did) and so doesn't just click his fingers to make it so.

Answer (score 0):

#### They entertain him

Those little powerless creatures are fun to watch for Jimmy. How they struggle and try to come up with oh-so-great schemes to kill Jimmy - it's a nice distraction.

Once you have nothing to fear life might get boring if you don't have anything to occupy yourself with. Therefore Jimmy needs a distraction so he won't get mad. And that's also why they shouldn't be as powerful as him but also not as powerless as an ant. Humans are creative - given enough time they can come up with interesting weapons and tactics and they replicate pretty fast. Also it's nice to watch them fight with each other - it's like god's television.

That also explains why he helps humans from time to time - it's a nice distraction from the boring being-super-powerful everyday life. And it might steer promising individuals to something greater so that they one day will achieve something that might be worthwhile to "fight" for some time.